# Rails – assign an order number to each record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

So I am importing passages from a book into my application. I am giving all the passages in a given book the class Passage. i.e. Passage.all

I do have many books so I also have a class Book. Therefore, when I am finding all the passages from one book I call:

```
Passage.where(book_id: self.book_id)
```

When I use the where method, does it preserve the "natural order", which Passage.all would generally return. If not, I could change the code to:

```
Passage.where(book_id: self.book_id).order("created_at ASC")
```

Anyway, I then proceed to write this code:

```
a = Passage.where(book_id: self.book_id)     
b = a.index(self)+1     
self.passage_number = b
```

---

[first line: returns all the passages in the book]

[second line: returns their number in the array + 1 to account for the 0 starting value thing (pardon the colloquialism)]

[third line: assigns that index value to the passage number]

Ultimately, I am trying to compute passage numbers, without having to hard code them.

SO WHAT'S MY ISSUE? Right now I am getting three passage #3's, and two passage #4's. My last passage is this:

```
Passage.last.passage_number = 217 
Passage.where(book_id: 5).count = 241
```

It is skipping numbers and incorrectly indexing, so I think I need to code a better method! What's a better way to index an array in this context?

Comment: Do you have `passage_number` attribute in `Passage` model?

Comment: Yes. So Passage.where(book_id: 5)[0].passage_number should = 1
and  Passage.where(book_id: 5)[1].passage_number should = 2. It starts off like this, but then starts to miscount. So Passage 4 is given passage_number = 3.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "natural order": without an order clause `Passage.all` may return things in any order the database wants (which could depend on things like location of items on disk, query plan etc).

The `first` and `last` methods are special in that they order by id if your relation does not already have an order applied to it.

If you need things in a specific order then add an order clause.

Comment: Thanks so much! I should realize that computers do whatever you tell them to do (and nothing more). So I should be explicit in my requests. I was importing an excel file and then running this code, so "natural order" was assumed to be the order the passages appear in the excel doc. After adding an order clause, the code ran as expected. Thanks for clarifying and the explanation of first and last methods.